# How to display tags product in view.phtml of Magento

Tags: magento, tags, product

I created new theme and use them for creating product. In view page, I don't see product tags. I review view.pthml in default and know that the tags in `"echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') "`, my view.phtml has it too but why it don't display tags

plz, any advice

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did after about 4 hours of research.

```
<?php
// instantiate the tags class for products
$_tags = new Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List();
?>

<ul class="product-tags">
<?php foreach($_tags->getTags() as $tag):?>
    <li><a href="<?=$tag->getTaggedProductsUrl()?>"><?=$tag->getName()?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

I don't like having to instantiate the class, so if I find a more elegant way I'll update my post. But at least it a php only solution.

Comment: I did the same thing, but its not working, am i missing anythign. I put it inside the themes folder app/design/frontend/default/jm_book/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Does your catalog.xml's catalog/product_view block define something like this?

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
```

In my Modern Theme store the tags are displayed using the template/tag/list.phtml hint path.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Boss Ninja: it works perfectly if your tag.xml file is enabled in layout directory (app/design/frontend/default/default/layout).

Comment: I am changed tag.xml but still getting 2 products in tag page. Any idea on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Define at XML layout in catalog_product_view section:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
```

And then in your phtml where you want it to display:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
```

Ensure that Mage_Tag module is enabled at "System --> Configuration --> Advanced".